# return meaningfull custom http response in Asp.net Core web api

Tags: .net, http, httpresponsemessage

Hi I want to create middleware for Asp.net core to wrap  http response that returns response like below

```
{
"count":1,"timestamp":"2021-12-18T01:13:41.2985038+05:00",
"status":"Success",
"results":[
{
"mayPrint":null,"mayEdit":null,"mayAddCopy":null,"mayDelete":null,"mayOverride":null
}
]}
```

I created middleware but it truncate the response and give error can't parse JSON and also it displays extra slashes in the results array

```
"results":"[{\"code\":\"465\",
```

[image]

My code is below.

```
public class ResponseMiddleware
{
    public class ResponseClass
    {
        public int count { get; set; }

        public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }

        public string status { get; set; }

        public object results { get; set; }
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    }
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    public ResponseMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (IsSwagger(context))
            await this._next(context);
        else
        {
            var existingBody = context.Response.Body;
            using (var newBody = new MemoryStream())
            {
                context.Response.Body = newBody;
                await _next(context);
                var newResponse = await FormatResponse(context.Response);
                context.Response.Body = new MemoryStream();
                newBody.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                context.Response.Body = existingBody;
                var newContent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(new StreamReader(newBody).ReadToEnd());

                // Send modified content to the response body.
                //
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(newResponse);
            }
        }
            
    }

    private bool IsSwagger(HttpContext context)
    {
        return context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/swagger");
    }
    private async Task<string> FormatResponse(HttpResponse response)
    {
        //We need to read the response stream from the beginning...and copy it into a string...I'D LIKE TO SEE A BETTER WAY TO DO THIS
        //
        response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var content = await new StreamReader(response.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        var Response = new ResponseClass(); 
        Response.status = response.StatusCode==200? "success": "Error";
        if (!IsResponseValid(response))
        {
            Response.ErrorMessage = content;
        }
        else
        {
            Response.results = content;
        }
        Response.count = response.ToString().Length;
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Response);

        //We need to reset the reader for the response so that the client an read it
        response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return $"{json}";
    }

    private bool IsResponseValid(HttpResponse response)
    {
        if ((response != null)
            && (response.StatusCode == 200
            || response.StatusCode == 201
            || response.StatusCode == 202))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool. But you haven't asked anything

Comment: @JamesZ now I have edit the question please help me if you could. It has formatted issues and as well logical issue.